# MacBook Pro Retina problems Wifi connection

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, wifi

i recently bought a power Mac but it recognizes my dedicated wifi but when I got to open a window no connection.
And that's when it connects on wifi after many attempts.

My iPhone and iPad are working online fine.

I am using xfinity as my internet provider.

Any help?

Henry

Comment: Help is on the way! But need more information from you. What is your setting on the Mac for that WiFi.